# How to make tesseract work for different kinds of images?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am working on a digit recognition task using Tesseract and OpenCV. I did use it and came to a solution that is specific for a particular image. If I change my image I do not obtain correct results. I should change the threshold value according to the image. The steps I did was:

1. Cropping the image to find an appropriate region
2. Change image into grayscale
3. Using Gaussian Blur
4. Taking appropriate threshold
5. passing the image through Tesseract

So, My question is how can I make my code generic i.e. it can be used for different images without updating my code.
[image]
While working on this image I processed as`

```
imggray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(imggray,(5,5), 0)
imgDil=cv2.dilate(imgBlur,np.ones((5,5),np.uint8),iterations=1)
imgEro=cv2.erode(imgDil,np.ones((5,5),np.uint8),iterations=2)
ret,imgthresh=cv2.threshold(imgEro,28,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )
```

[image]
And for this Image as

```
imggray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgBlur=cv2.GaussianBlur(imggray,(5,5), 0)
imgDil=cv2.dilate(imgBlur,np.ones((5,5),np.uint8),iterations=0)
imgEro=cv2.erode(imgDil,np.ones((5,5),np.uint8),iterations=0)
ret,imgthresh=cv2.threshold(imgEro,37,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )
```

I had to change the value of iterations and the minimum threshold to obtain proper results. What can be the solution so I should not change the values?

Comment: add some sample images when you're asking questions like this.

Comment: There is a great Python [tutorial for thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) in the official OpenCV docs. You should try adaptive or otsu thresholding.  Dilate/Erode/Blur might not be necessary